# How to hook into selected item when inheriting jQuery Autocomplete

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I am trying to extend autocomplete so when an item is selected an secondary label is displayed. For example, given an autocomplete that displays projects, the project name would be displayed in a span tag next to the input box that contains the code.

Looking at the autocomplete source code I see that the dropdown of filtered values is rendered using the jQuery menu widget and that when specific keys are typed in the textbox, different functions are called on the menu widget. For example, when enter and tab are pressed, the select() function of the menu widget is called.

The menu widget is configured so that when the selected event is raised, the autocomplete widget gets the selected item and raises its own select event and then displays the items value in the textbox.

So, given the following code

```
(function ($, undefined) {
    $.widget('xyz.autocompletePlus', $.ui.autocomplete, {
        options: {
            selectedDescriptor: null
        },

        _create: function () {
            $.ui.autocomplete.prototype._create.call(this, this.options);

            if (!this.options.selectedDescriptor) {
                $("<span class='ui-xyz-autocomplete-label'>").insertAfter(this.element).html('Nothing selected');
            }
        },

        _setOption: function (name, value) {
            $.ui.autocomplete.prototype._setOption.call(this, arguments);
        },

        destroy: function () {
            $.ui.autocomplete.prototype.destroy.call(this);
            $.Widget.prototype.destroy.call(this);
        }
    });
} (jQuery));
```

how do I hook into the code that gets called when an item is selected so I can insert my own logic? The idea would be that instead of executing

```
if ( false !== self._trigger( "select", event, { item: item } ) ) {
   self.element.val( item.value );
}
```

I would want *something* like (not the actual code but gets the point across)

```
if ( false !== self._trigger( "select", event, { item: item } ) ) {
   self.element.val( item.value );
   this.options.selectedDescriptor.html( item.description);
}
```

If I was not inheriting but encapsulating an autocomplete in a new widget I could just bind to the autocomplete select event and do my thing, but with the inheritance I am stumped.

**Edit:**

Added the autocomplete source that I need to replace or hook into. It starts at line 6137 of jquery-ui-1.8.22.js

```
this.menu = $( "<ul></ul>" )
   ...
   ...
   .menu({
      focus: function( event, ui ) {
         ...
         ...
         }
      },
      selected: function( event, ui ) {
         var item = ui.item.data( "item.autocomplete" ),
            previous = self.previous;

         // only trigger when focus was lost (click on menu)
         if ( self.element[0] !== doc.activeElement ) {
            self.element.focus();
            self.previous = previous;
            // #6109 - IE triggers two focus events and the second
            // is asynchronous, so we need to reset the previous
            // term synchronously and asynchronously :-(
            setTimeout(function() {
               self.previous = previous;
               self.selectedItem = item;
            }, 1);
         }

         if ( false !== self._trigger( "select", event, { item: item } ) ) {
            self.element.val( item.value );
         }
         // reset the term after the select event
         // this allows custom select handling to work properly
         self.term = self.element.val();

         self.close( event );
         self.selectedItem = item;
      },
      ...
      ...
```

Thanks.

Comment: why dont you use autocomplete's 'select' option? http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-select

Answer (score 0):

The code you want to augment resides in a private event handler. Inheritance will indeed not help a lot with that.

You can, however, unbind the existing handler in your `_create()` method and register a new one that does what you want. Unfortunately, that involves copying the original handler's code:

```
_create: function() {
    $.ui.autocomplete.prototype._create.call(this, this.options);

    if (!this.options.selectedDescriptor) {
        this.options.selectedDescriptor
            = $("<span class='ui-xyz-autocomplete-label'>")
                .insertAfter(this.element).html("Nothing selected");
    }
    this.menu.element.off("menuselected")
                     .on("menuselected", function(event, ui) {
        var item = ui.item.data("item.autocomplete");
        if (false !== this._trigger("select", event, { item: item })) {
            this.element.val(item.value);
        }
        this.close(event);
        this.previous = this.element.val();
        // only trigger when focus was lost (click on menu)
        var doc = this.element[0].ownerDocument;
        if (this.element[0] !== doc.activeElement) {
            this.element.focus();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: This does not seem to be working as written. Just calling this.menu.element.off('menuselected') causes a TypeError: this.menu.element.off is not a function error. I guess the problem is getting a proper reference to the underlying menu widget. Because of limited formatting in these comments I posted the original code in a separate question above.

Comment: @Jason, maybe the version of jQuery you're using is less than 1.7. If that's the case, try `unbind()` instead of `off()` (and `bind()` instead of `on()`).